# Differenciate the `layout_gravity` and `layout_centerVertical` function

Tags: android-layout

Do `layout_gravity="center_vertical"` and `layout_centerVertical="true"` will result the same thing in the different layouts?

All the answers previously mentioned for this question said these attributes work for different layouts but nobody told about their actual function.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to refer documentation of [android:layout_gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity) and [android:layout_centerVertical](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_centerVertical).

Form my thought, Both are identically same. **Widget is placed in centers this child vertically within its parent/ container**.